# How to use two returned values from a function in another function? MAIN()

Tags: python

**MY PROGRAM:**

```
findGrid(n):   #This function takes one parameter.
    row = n + 1
    col = row ** 2

    return  row, col                  #Return two values

calculate(a, b):
    p = a + b

    return p

main():
    x = eval(input("Enter a number: "))
    y = findGrid(x)
```

**My question here is that how to use two return values from the function `findGrid()` in the function `calculate()`?** Please help!

Comment: `calculate(*findGrid(x))` An asterisk before an iterable value in an expression "unpacks" the value and distributes its elements as positional arguments. In this case, the return value of findGrid is of type tuple, which is an iterable.

Comment: Does that asterisk work for more than two returned values?

Comment: Yup, works for any length iterable. Any function that returns multiple values at once in Python is actually just returning a tuple! The tuple can also be "unpacked" with an assignment statement, e.g. `a, b = findGrid(x)`. But if you are just going to be throwing those variables into another function you might as well just chain the return value into the other function with an asterisk. It's clean and concise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other answer does not work.  You need to declare your functions properly.

```
def findGrid(n):   #This function takes one parameter.
    row = n + 1
    col = row ** 2

    return  row, col                  #Return two values

def calculate(a, b):
    a = a + 2
    b = a // 2

    return a, b

def main():
    x = int(input("Enter a number: "))
    y,z = findGrid(x)
    a,b = calculate(y, z)
    print a
    print b

main()
```

Comment: I guess s\he wants to know how to call them in the same line, like @Shashank described.